# Replace() only works with one cofiguration of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a piece of code that duplicates a `<table>` but in the process changes id's. It took hours but I eventually got this to happen with:

```
var lookFor = 'url' + parseInt(uploadCount);
++uploadCount; //used to create a unique id
var replaceWith = 'url'+parseInt(uploadCount);
var regex = new RegExp(lookFor, 'g');
var tableHTML = '<table class="user-url-table" style="opacity:0;" id="url' + uploadCount + '">' + $('table.user-url-table').first().html().replace(regex, replaceWith) + '</table>';
$(tableHTML).insertAfter($('table.user-url-table').last());
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
var lookFor = 'url' + parseInt(uploadCount);
var tableHTML = '<table class="user-url-table" style="opacity:0;" id="url' + uploadCount + '">' + $('table.user-url-table').first().html() + '</table>';
++uploadCount;
var replaceWith = 'url'+parseInt(uploadCount);
var regex = new RegExp(lookFor, 'g');
tableHTML = $('table.user-url-table').first().html().replace(regex, replaceWith);
```

But shouldn't they do exactly the same job....? The first piece of code surely just does everything in one line, whereas the second forms the `<table>` and then changes all instances of the id in it.

Comment: Can you set up a demo to show what one of these tables look like? It seems like you're making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PdSTP/1/  the idea is that a user enters a url and the `blur()` event on the textarea makes an ajax call to a php script that updates elements on the page according to the url or whether it's valid - this is where the unique id is used. There's a plus icon on the page to allow the user to add more url entries and it's this that calls the above code. I use a table just for formatting.

Comment: Why do you have the same ID on multiple elements?

Comment: Very poor organisation on my part. It's a project that keeps changing just slightly and I've been lazy in keeping the code tidy. The main `id` I'm after is the one with the `.url-indicator`; this element has it's opacity animated depending on the integrity of the url.

Comment: `.url-indicator` is an ID? I'm confused as to what you're actually tring to do.. and you know you could just use `$('item').attr('id','newIdHere')` right? `newItem = $('item').clone()` first to make a copy.. **If you post a before and after example of the HTML, I'm sure someone can help**

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there should be no need to `parseInt` when concatenating `uploadCount` onto strings, it will just be immediately coerced back to a string right away. I'm assuming it is already a number anyway since you are `++`ing it without errors. So `'url + parseInt(uploadCount)` is needlessly taking a number, converting it to a string, then parsing the string as an integer and then converting that number back into a string. Also, when using `parseInt` [always use a radix](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'll admit I was clutching at straws when the replace() wouldn't work. Will definitely delete! That's a useful link too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors on the second code. First, when you do `tableHTML = $('table.user-url-table').first().html().replace(regex, replaceWith);` on the last line, you throw away the preparation you did. You override the value of `tableHTML`.

The second error is that the result is not appended to the document, like you did with `insertAfter` in the first code.

To make if work, replace the last line with `$('table.user-url-table').after(tableHTML.replace(regex, replaceWith));`. This will insert tableHTML with the replaced id's `after` the first table.

Another way, much simpler, of doing the same thing is this:

```
var firstTable = $("#url1 tbody").html();
var result = "";
for (i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
    result += '<table class="user-url-table" style="opacity:0.2;" id="url'
              + i + '">' + firstTable.replace("url1", "url" + i) + '</table>';
}
$("#url1").after(result);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/ydEPr/

Comment: Thanks ariel and everyone. Schoolboy errors in my code. I blame too much caffeine.